# Linkedin share button embed

Tags: plugins, linkedin-api, share-button

How do I embed the LinkedIn share button on my website? I already found a javascript code on Linkedin's developer site, but it doesn't work.

I want to embed linkedin share button on my website

Comment: Please provide more details. What was the code you found and tried already? Is it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin or something else? And what did not work about what you tried (e.g., what was the error message)?

Comment: <script src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://www.linkedin.com"></script> this code is not working

Comment: You didn't provide all of the requested details. What isn't working about this code? Are you getting a console error of some kind? Is a share button not appearing? Please provide further details.